# How to put break statement inside a condition which is inside a switch case in korn script

Tags: shell, ksh

I am writing a korn script to process some fixed/user provided input. I am not able to run this script as I am getting syntax error ***`)' unexpected***. I am thinking that it is because I am using a break inside the if statement, where the if is inside a switch case. I have just picked up scripting last week and would really appreciate any help on this.
P.S There is a reason for using korn script.

```
  #!/usr/bin/ksh93

  typeset -A fileset_list               #fileset_list is associative

  fileset_list=([All filesets]="A B C D E"
           [A]=AA
           [B]=BB
           [C]="CC CCC CCCC CCCC"
           [D]=DD
           [E]="EE EEE EEEE EEEE EEEEE"
          )

        fileset="All filesets"
        echo "Recent update has found following unsupported filesets on the system:\n${fileset_list["All filesets"]}"
        echo "Do you want to delete all the listed filesets along with their dependencies Y/N"
        while true; do
                read yn
                case $yn in
                [Yy]* )
                        set -A delete_list ${fileset_list["All filesets"]}
                        uninstall_fun
                        break;;

                [Nn]* )
                        echo "Do you want to delete the partial list Y/N"
                        while true; do
                                read y_n
                                case $y_n in
                                [Yy]* ) echo "Enter the space separated filesets from the above list for deletion"
                                        read user_list
                                        echo "You have entered $user_list\nIs the list correct Y/N"
                                        read selection

                                        if [[ $selection == [Yy]* ]]
                                        then
                                                set -A delete_list $user_list
                                                uninstall_fun
                                                break;; #<<<<ISSUE
                                        else
                                                echo "Do you want to re-enter list Y/N" #<<<<<need this to go back and read y_n
                                        fi

                        #               break;;
                                [Nn]* )
                                        break;;

                                    * ) echo "Please answer yes(y) or no(n).";;

                                esac
                        done

                        break;;
                * ) echo "Please answer yes(y) or no(n).";;
                esac
        done

uninstall_fun(){
 echo "In uninstall_fun"
}
```

Comment: Multiple syntax issues, recommend http://www.shellcheck.net/ to fix your syntax issues.

Comment: I think you need [dhag's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200383/205814). as he says `break [n]`. Exit from within a for, while, until, or select loop.  If n is specified, break n levels.  n must be ≥ 1.  If n is greater than
       the number of enclosing loops, all enclosing loops  are  exited.
       The  return  value is 0 unless n is not greater than or equal to
       1.

Comment: When you change  `while true` into a test (using something like yn_valid or testing against `[yYnN]`), you can change the boolean and make the code easier to understand. Also consider using a function when the code is getting too long (so use a function `delete_partial_list`).

Comment: The `break;;` shouldn't be a problem. After braking out of the `while..done` the next thing you is braking out of the other `while ..done`.

Comment: @WalterA I appreciate your suggestions on coding practice. But my particular issue is not getting solved. I am saying the issue is with break;; because when I remove "break;; #<<<<ISSUE" and un-comment  " #               break;;" then the code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `;;` is used at the end of each `case` block. You had one in the middle of the if statement, but the `case` block is not finished yet.
The line with `break;; # <<<<ISSUE` should become `break # without ;;`,
and the line `#               break;;` should be `;;`.

```
[Yy]* ) echo "Enter the space separated filesets from the above list for deletion"
        read user_list
        echo "You have entered $user_list\nIs the list correct Y/N"
        read selection

        if [[ $selection == [Yy]* ]]
        then
           set -A delete_list $user_list
           uninstall_fun
           break # Without ;;
        else
           echo "Do you want to re-enter list Y/N" #<<<<<need this to go back and read y_n
        fi

        ;; # Needed here
[Nn]* )
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for.